# Getting Error of using OneHotEncoder and SimpleImputer in a Single Pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, one-hot-encoding, data-wrangling

how can I actually proceed it in a single pipeline, is there any value missing or wrongly defined something.

```
 #instantiate
imputer = SimpleImputer()
ohe = OneHotEncoder(use_cat_names=True)

#fit
imputer.fit(X_train)
ohe.fit(X_train)

#transform
XT_train = imputer.transform(X_train["lat","lon"])
XT_train = ohe.transform(X_train["neighborhood"])



model = make_pipeline(
    SimpleImputer(),
    OneHotEncoder(use_cat_names=True),
    Ridge()
)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

[image]

Error I found in the console like

Answer (score 1):

```
#instantiate
imputer = SimpleImputer()
ohe = OneHotEncoder(use_cat_names=True)

#fit
imputer.fit(X_train)
ohe.fit(X_train)

#transform
XT_train = imputer.transform(X_train["lat","lon"])
XT_train = ohe.transform(X_train["neighborhood"])
```

> Remove All above lines of code.  Because, OneHotEncoder Automatically
> detect categorical data in the feature matrix, like this is true for
> also SimpleImputer ->> it can identify numerical  NAN values and then
> fill it.

```
# Build Model
model = make_pipeline(
    OneHotEncoder(use_cat_names=True),
    SimpleImputer(),
    Ridge()
)
# Fit model
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: OneHotEncoder(use_cat_names=True) does not work anymore. It throws an error TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_cat_names'

Answer (score 0):

Yes its magical under the hood, but OHE has to come before SimpleImputer.
If you start the pipeline with SimpleImputer, you get the error as you did, I did that too. But changing the order solved the issue, and here is the pipeline

```
 Pipeline

OneHotEncoder
OneHotEncoder(cols=['neighborhood'], use_cat_names=True)

SimpleImputer
SimpleImputer()

Ridge
Ridge()
```